# Some problems for Android SDK tool revision 7

Tags: android

Updated Android SDK tools 7 (for Eclipse, windows 7 32 bits). But I
got some problems:

1. Android looks changed some package name, For example, the
   "android.intent…"was changed to “android.content.intent…”; the
   “android.permission…” was changed to “android.Manifest.permission…”.
   If I change the old package name to the new one, the emulator will not
   work for the application.
2. The tools 7 replaceed some drop-down list selection to Browser
   selection, for example, the IntentFilter Attributes selection and
   permission attributes selection no longer have drop-down list
   selection instead of a “Browser”.

Did I make anything wrong? Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html) blog post, will help you handle the API versions issue.